# Cannot Mount Harddisk from Macbook to recover files

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I've looked around and cannot find a solution to this problem.

I am working on an old Macbook that died and am trying to salvage some files form the disk. I am Using Ubuntu live to try and accomplish this.

I have determined that the partition I need access too is /dev/sda2, however it does not seem that Ubuntu is recognizing a file system type when I try to mount this drive.

Is this drive possibly damaged beyond being salvaged or what can I try to mount this thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty routine thing to do. Linux supports about every filesystem ever invented.

This link is has a write-up of how to mount a mac filesystem and copy files

https://superuser.com/q/84446/152045

See the response with 123 votes - it addresses the case you are dealing with. The top response with the green check mark doesn't apply to your case